# How to describe Immutable.js Map shape with Flow

Tags: immutable.js

I would like to describe the shape of a map using Immutable's flow type definitions.

You can describe the shape of an object by:

```
const stateShape: {
  id: number,
  isActive: boolean
} = {
  id: 123,
  isActive: true
};
```

Is there something similar for Immutable's Maps?

Comment: I've been trying to solve this problem as well, but so far haven't found the answer. This issue might be relevant: https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/203

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## TL;DR;

No, but using Records you can get Flow to typecheck the shape but not the types.

## Longform

The *correct* answer would be: **no, since maps don't have shapes** *(at least in Flow and Immutable)*. But *Immutable* does have a type for "Maps" with shapes. That would be **Records**. But for reasons described below (since it's not strictly relevant) the flow libdef for `Immutable.Record` is very loose and actually doesn't check for shapes.

### A better Record libdef

If we ignore the (arguably unnecessary) feature of directly accessing Record properties, we can create a better libdef. The would look like this:

```
declare class Record<T: Object> {
  static <T: Object>(spec: T, name?: string): Record<T>;
  get: <A>(key: $Keys<T>) => A;
  set<A>(key: $Keys<T>, value: A): Record<T>;
  remove(key: $Keys<T>): Record<T>;
}
```

**With this declaration we can define the shape of the Record**. [Here it is in action](https://flowtype.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwErgPY2AHgBUAueAeQCMArcAFwD54BvAKHnmRqhoEsx5CSFamHoAKZAAdwJAgBp4AOygBbEAH4SHGNwUBzAJQlMYHPgJ0A3K3i6QNEngCCdUQGsQATxIASANKfkQjp9eABeBkcrNmQ7Jxd3L3g-AKD5ADcoCABXEBJHQwxsXCCo+DhlLDSQN08ffw9A8wLjUxLmAF9mZhMFDngADzDCk1xRRngoEgByGhgcqfh2-S6AehX4ADEobghkeRR4bhp2AAssLIhgZn6AOhiaUSnyKfkAJmW1+EddrHgAM22u2uNygzE+BBO3DQyDOF2AExEWUyEA8-0BwNsDymUCmIQAVPBXswgA). But we still can't define the types of the actual values. Flow does define an undocumented `$PropertyType<T, K>` type. Which takes an object `T` and a string literal `K`. To make `$PropertyType` work in our case it would need to work for `$Keys<T>` which is a string union type. A few weeks ago an issue was opened to make this happen. [It can be found here](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2310).

### Difference between Map and Object

In flow they are fairly different. This is a Map:

```
type MyMaps = { [key: string]: number }
```

The actual keys are unknown. The only thing Flow knows, is that all keys must be strings and all values must be numbers. An Object type on the other hand looks something like:

```
type MyObject = { a: string, x: boolean }
```

When creating or changing an object, `newObj`, of type `MyObject` Flow, will check that `newObj.a` is a string and `newObj.x` is a boolean.

### Why the current definition is so loose

A Record exposes every key/value pair through direct key access.

```
type R = { a: string }
const r = Record({ a: 'Supa' })
r.a === r.get('a')
```

This would require the type definition of `r` to be an intersect of `Record<R>` and `R` (not exactly, but it's close enough). So:

```
(r: R & Record<R>)
```

This doesn't work because Flow lacks support for intersect types with objects. [Here's how that looks in action](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAggdmCmAeBDAtgBwDazAewGZgCVYBjbAJwBMwBXAZwEsoBzMAFwAstjqyzYpWYCrFyN6retigA6AFBhwAFU5CRYiVLDFEMAEZZc2alCqc+ALjDtWrVLXPBgTce2q7ppZMFyJisXdjYANbA9MjI1KyIupgAtABWtMAx2LrAyIi0rLBkwKwAnqiwscKiUOKSUElhEVExsNKJ0rjo2ADuAMQAMgBsAEwALPIgwLKywsToiHxaU7S0hCTkFAA8ipYA8rrxJKwAfGAA3vJgWYgSxGBrm9u7ewAUtEXElooANGBQKLAA-JZZZEYTAAlJZQIowAAyRakShrPYjHT5ADcJ0cYAAyvRhJ9sMJLAASADSsHyC3oC0QYAAbjl8lpAugPrpIjQTNhuMh+NkqLhYOceFg2ux6MR2GATkxYKwVhAHkFSYSSWT4aDIKiwKdpbL5YqwMTSbR4R9qYh0NRYJYIGrwVCYct4SMOBSNWA+MhsLT7gr8krDaqwSAIdCiLDVooEXkRbRUQBfMakKqCeBgAC89so90OYEQlgA5KwyBa82BY8CxujlBTTuwjOgqBwyO1ZPBpLRpfc87o8x8+uXK9Ga3WqGbaNg2Owm21Tow-GAAAatxDzsDVqkAoEt6RS1idxB54EKMB9WRAA).

Comment: is this still true or has flow been developed further since this answer?

Comment: Check RecordOf<> and RecordFactory<> new types, from immutable

Comment: import type { Map } from 'immutable';