# Flow: Typechecking a complex Immutable shape using fromJS()?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js, flowtype

How do you typecheck the shape of an Immutable.JS data structure generated from `fromJS` using Flow? Plain old JS blobs can be typed very accurately using an object literal notation:

```
type ObjectShape = {
  a: number,
  b: string,
  c: {
    d: number,
  },
  e: Array<number>
};

const obj: ObjectShape = { // hyper-accurate
  a: 1,
  b: '2',
  c: {
    d: 3,
  },
  e: [4]
}
```

However, on the Immutable.js side, there seem to be two major complications:

1. It appears that Immutable.js's `fromJS` method returns `any` (https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/type-definitions/immutable.js.flow#L764), so the following is not caught as an error in Flow:

   ```
   const map: boolean = fromJS(obj) // this is totally not true, but Flow can't tell
   ```
2. It appears that map shapes cannot be described using an object-like notation per [How to describe Immutable.js Map shape with Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033339/how-to-describe-immutable-js-map-shape-with-flow) (or is this information outdated?).

I'm genuinely confused on how to get Flow to understand Immutable.js, maps in particular. From what I can tell, Flow loses a lot of intelligence about the codebase when the data is living within Immutable.js structures instead of plain JS primitives.

Comment: what about https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed , you can just load the Map type defintion

Comment: There are no definitions for immutabe.js on flow-typed, they are included directly with the immutable.js package from npm. However, the Map definition included with immutable.js right now does not appear to let you define a shape: https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/type-definitions/immutable.js.flow#L489

Answer (score 2):

EDIT 2018-05-14: The as-yet-unreleased version 4.0 of immutable-js has full support for this. When you create a Record, it will infer its type from the object passed to it, or you can manually type the factory as `Record<TProps>`. The latest release as of now is as 4.0.0-rc.9, but the project has been [comatose](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/1215) for about six months, so you may want to just read up on the known bugs (to avoid them or, in a custom build, fix them) and use the RC.

---

You would theoretically have to use a Record() which encoded the expected shape and *then* add typechecking...

Except that statically typing the actual **members** of this immutable-js structure would sadly not be possible, because of [certain](https://github.com/facebook/flow/pull/3023) [features](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2310) that are lacking in flow.

There is currently a pair of pull requests ([first](https://github.com/facebook/flow/pull/3023), [second](https://github.com/facebook/flow/pull/2952)) open to add the necessary features to the typechecker, but they are fairly involved and the process of reviewing and integrating them seems to be going on internally at Facebook.

I suspect that as soon as those are merged, flow-typed definitions that encode the new hotness will be up almost immediately, even if the immutable-js project doesn't integrate them as fast.

Note: if you want to provide feedback, please do not leave "+1" or "when is it done comments"; those are not accepted style for that repository. Use the reaction/voting feature instead.

Comment: I see that the PR's are now closed. Any example on how to do this, if it's possible now?

Comment: Instead of those PRs, the solution the flow folks arrived at was to add a *new* type function, $ElementType, that has the necessary features. See e.g. https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBA0hJQLxQOQGt4oNwChSSgBUkoBvKDEALigDsBXAWwCMIAnKAX1wBMIBjADYBDNtABuoqGDYB7MDQAkAUUERGEWsELgIAHkIAaOCAB8uIA