# Flowtype immutable js map never produces a flow error

Tags: javascript, flowtype, immutable.js

I can't get this immutablejs map to error:

```
const alertModal: Map<AlertModalState> = Map(
  {
    'isAlertModalOpen': false,
    'alertModalTitle': '',
    'alertModalMessage': '',
    'height': 0,
    'hasYesNo': false
  }
)

type AlertModalState =  {
  isAlertModalOpen: boolean,
  alertModalTitle: string,
  alertModalMessage: string,
  height: number,
  hasYesNo: boolean
}
```

When I change the properties to have different names, they still don't produce a flow error. Is this code valid or should it produce an error?

Comment: See [width subtyping](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/width-subtyping/).

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [How to describe Immutable.js Map shape with Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033339/how-to-describe-immutable-js-map-shape-with-flow)

> Immutable does have a type for "Maps" with shapes